# Python, split a string at commas, except within quotes, ignoring whitespace

Tags: python, regex, csv, split

I've found some solutions, but the results I am getting don't match what I'm expecting.

I want to take a string, and split it at commas, except when the commas are contained within double quotation marks. I would like to ignore whitespace. I can live with losing the double quotes in the process, but it's not necessary.

Is csv the best way to do this? Would a regex solution be better?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

import csv

s = 'abc,def, ghi, "jkl, mno, pqr","stu"'

result = csv.reader(s, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

for r in result: 
    print r

# Should display:
# abc
# def
# ghi
# jkl, mno, pqr
# stu
#
# But I get:
# ['a']
# ['b']
# ['c']
# ['', '']
# ['d']
# ['e']
# ['f']
# ['', '']
# [' ']
# ['g']
# ['h']
# ['i']
# ['', '']
# [' ']
# ['jkl, mno, pqr']
# ['', '']
# ['stu']

print r[1]  # Should be "def" but I get and "list index out of range" error.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the regular expression

```
".+?"|[\w-]+
```

This will match double-quotes, followed by any characters, until the next double-quote is found - OR, it will match word characters (no commas nor quotes).

https://regex101.com/r/IThYf7/1

```
import re
s = 'abc,def, ghi, "jkl, mno, pqr","stu"'
for r in re.findall(r'".+?"|[\w-]+', s):
    print(r)
```

If you want to get rid of the `"`s around the quoted sections, the best I could figure out by using the `regex` module (so that `\K` was usable) was:

```
(?:^"?|, ?"?)\K(?:(?<=").+?(?=")|[\w-]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/IThYf7/3

Comment: Works almost perfectly... But for some reason it is splitting on "-" characters as well. I should have included some hyphenated data in my sample string, like hello-there..

Comment: Use a character set rather than just `\w`, since `\w` doesn't match `-` - change the final alternation to `[\w-]+`

Comment: The problem with the dot character here is, that it will apply to every character until the end of the string. So it should be replaced by the set of all characters except for a double quote: `[^"]`

Comment: Thanks! Just figured it out myself using the link you provided. It will be nice when I can read regex like English.  :)

Comment: @SvenKrüger No, because the repetition is *lazy* - it'll match as few characters as possible, until it finds the next `"`. (Check out the regex101 link.) Lazy repeating is nicer than negated character sets, I think, when possible.

Comment: @CertainPerformance The output of `re.findall(r'".+?"|\w+', s)` is `['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl, mno, pqr","stu']`. Have a close look at the last element `'jkl, mno, pqr","stu'`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance My bad!... I entered `r'".*?"|\w+'` - with asterisk instead of plus... :)

Comment: @SvenKrüger Ah, the *second* regex, not the first. I didn't check it carefully, thanks. I'm drawing a blank without `\K`, especially given the possibility of inputs like `abc,def, ghi, "jkl, mno, pqr","stu",",",",","foo"`. Hmm..

Comment: @SvenKrüger Ah, I think I got it :) An interesting problem

Comment: @CertainPerformance The dot at regex101 is lazy. In Python it does not seem to be lazy.

Comment: @SvenKrüger What do you mean? The dot doesn't repeat by itself, only the repeater tokens like `*`, `+`, `?` repeat, and are all by default greedy, unless proceeded by a `?`, which should make it lazy? That's how it should work in all sane regex environments (that support the idea of greedy vs lazy). It seems to work as expected in Python for me

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `csv` you could have another nice approach which is supported by the newer `regex` module (i.e. `pip install regex`):

```
"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,\s*
```

---

This reads as follows:

```
"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*FAIL) # match everything between two double quotes and "forget" about them
|                     # or
,\s*                  # match a comma and 0+ whitespaces
```

---

In `Python`:

```
import regex as re

rx = re.compile(r'"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,\s*')
string = 'abc,def, ghi, "jkl, mno, pqr","stu"'

parts = rx.split(string)
print(parts)
```

This yields

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', '"jkl, mno, pqr"', '"stu"']
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/AdukBQ/1).