# Python pandas separate dataframe by commas, except commas inside of quotations

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a very large csv file (2+ million rows) which is separated by commas. Except there are a few entries such as Company Name and a value field where fields can contain commas inside quotations.

E.g:

product1,"23-12-2021 21:37:22.567",50,18.32,"Company, A"

product1,"23-12-2021 21:37:24.237","1,000",17.34,"Company, C"

**Note that when the value field after the datetime is >= 1000 it adds the comma and quotations**. As a result of the above when I try:

```
pd.read_csv(r'C:\example_file.csv', delimiter=",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='"', encoding='utf-8')
```

It throws a pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 24 fields in line x, saw 25

I've managed a workaround to get it into a dataframe using this:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

file = pd.read_csv(r'C:\example_file.csv', delimiter="\t", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, encoding='utf-8')
df = pd.Dataframe(file)

column_list = df_columns
column_string = str(column_list[0])
# column_list[0] returns index with 24 column names
column_string_split = column_string.split(",")

df.rename(columns{df.columns[0]: 'fill'}, inplace=True)

new_df = pd.Dataframe(data_df['fill'].str.split(',').tolist(), columns=column_string_split)
```

I understand what I've tried so far isnt optimal and ideally I would separate the data when I read it in but I'm at a loss on how to progress. I've been looking into regex expressions to exclude commas inside quotations (such as [Python, split a string at commas, except within quotes, ignoring whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52962287/python-split-a-string-at-commas-except-within-quotes-ignoring-whitespace)) but nothing as worked. Any ideas on how to str.split commas except within quotes?

Comment: A standard `pd.read_csv()` parses your sample data just fine.  Commas inside quotes won't be used a delimiters.

Comment: You don't need to do `read_csv` with `delimeter="\t"`? Just `read_csv` by default will ignore the `,` inside the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the `.csv` you gave :

> product1,"23-12-2021 21:37:22.567",50,18.32,"Company, A"
> product1,"23-12-2021 21:37:24.237","1,000",17.34,"Company, C"

First, as explained in the comments by @[Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4718350/chris) and @[Quang Hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang), a standard [**`pandas.read_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) will ignore the comma inside the quotes.

Second, you can pass the `thousands` parameter to [**`pandas.read_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to get rid of the comma for all the numbers `> 999`.

Try this :

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\example_file.csv', encoding='utf-8', thousands=",")
```